# Mantener el valor de un option select después de un submit

Tags: php

Estoy intentando que una vez seleccionada una opción en un `select`, al enviar el formulario se mantenga esa opción seleccionada. Estoy intentado implementarlo sobre este simple ejemplo:

```js
<?php
$valores=array(1=>"opcion 1", "opcion 2", "opcion 3");
?>
 
<form action="" method="POST">
<select name="Select">
    <option value='0'>Seleccionar opcion</option>
    <?php
    foreach($valores as $key=>$value)
    {
        
        if($_POST["Select"]==$key)
        {
            echo "<option value='".$key."' selected>".$value."</option>";
        }else{
            echo "<option value='".$key."'>".$value."</option>";
        }
    }
    ?>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>
```

El ejemplo anterior funciona correctamente y al intentar implementarlo sobre mi código no logro hacer que funcione correctamente, esto es lo que tengo escrito:

```js
                          echo "<form action='' method='POST'>
                                    <select name='selec'>
                                        <option value='0'>Selecciona opcion</option>";
                             // Lista los directorios
                                $directorio = opendir("adminUser/"); // Ruta Directorios
                                while ($ad = readdir($directorio)) {
                                    if(is_dir($ad)) {
                                    } else {
          $valores = array(1=>"" . $ad . "");

                                        foreach($valores as $key=>$value) {
          // Si coincide lo enviado con el valor
                                        if($_POST["selec"] == $key) {
                                        echo "<option value='".$key."' selected>".$value."</option>";
                                        } else {
                                        echo "<option value='".$key."'>".$value."</option>";
           }
          }
                                    }
        }
                              echo "</select>
                                    <input type='submit' value='enviar'>
                                </form>";
```

El tema es que el `option` `select` hace correctamente su función, muestra los nombres de los directorios pero al enviar el formulario no es capaz de mantener la opción seleccionada. Será porque estoy bloqueado y no sé ver donde estoy fallando?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

como consejo personal, evita usar HTML dentro de PHP.
Luego, respondiendo a tu consulta el error está en que todas las carpetas tenían el mismo ID `$valores = array(1=>"" . $ad . "");` . Hacia falta agregar una variable contador que aumente con el while. Te dejo el código modificado:

```
<?php
echo "<form action='' method='POST'>
    <select name='selec'>
        <option value='0'>Selecciona opcion</option>";
        // Lista los directorios
        $directorio = opendir("adminUser/"); // Ruta Directorios
        $id = 0;
        while ($ad = readdir($directorio)) {
            if(!is_dir($ad)) {
                $id++;
                $valores = array($id=>"" . $ad . "");
                foreach($valores as $key=>$value) {
                    // Si coincide lo enviado con el valor
                    if($_POST["selec"] == $key) {
                        echo "<option value='".$key."' selected>".$value."</option>";
                    } else {
                        echo "<option value='".$key."'>".$value."</option>";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
echo "</select>
    <input type='submit' value='enviar'>
</form>";
?>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu gran ayuda y explicaciones... lo acabo de testear y funciona perfecto. Por que me aconsejas evitar usar HTML dentro de php?

Comment: El mezclar PHP con HTML solo debe darse en casos excepcionales. (Ojo no es una norma, es mas bien como una opinión divida) Te dejo un articulo al respecto. https://thisinterestsme.com/mixing-php-html Saludos